# How to create a checked exception and use it in the header of a method?

Tags: java

For example:

```
int Method1() throws new MyException 
{
   // something here causes a MyException's exception.
}
```

I know that I should extend exception first. But how could I trigger the exception according the to the method's state ?

I want to be able to throw a MyException for whatever reason I choose, similar to how FileNotFoundException is thrown when file isn't found.

Comment: Go read this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor correction is required

```
 int Method1() throws Exception 
    {
    // based on your validation logic
    throw new MyException();
    }
```

**UPDATE:-** say you want to handle file not found exception

```
int Method1() throws Exception 
        {
          try
          {
            some file handling Code
          }
          Catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
          throw new MyException();// if you want to throw checked one otherwise below
          throw new RunTimeException();// for unchecked ones

         }
        }
```

Comment: Ok but then why should this "throws new MyException" be included in the header of the method ?? it doesn't make sense.. wouldn't it work the same if we have // int method1() {if (bla bla) throws new MyException; } and thanks a lot !

Comment: when you throw checked Exception you need throw clause in method definition.Please go thru http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for throwing an exception is very simple:

```
...
if (somethingIsWrong) {
    throw new MyException(); // May include optional parameters
}
```

Very often one of the parameters includes a message explaining what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If MyException is extended from Exception class then at any point in your method you can throw the exception by writing:

```
throw new MyException();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate the exception class. E.g.

```
if (i<0)
    throw new MyException();
```